# Моветон или нет?

Tags: php

Для меня всегда было очень важно название функций, классов, переменных. Я люблю, когда они состоят из одного слова, но это не всегда получается. Например, у меня есть модуль Admin (панель администратора) для которой я сделал файловый менеджер. Подключать файловый менеджер извне не представляется возможным. Для того, чтобы не было конфликта с другими методами, нужно к каждому методу, который имеет отношение к файловому менеджеру добавлять что-то типа `fm`. Но мне кажется это не красивым. Тогда я придумал такой вариант: я создаю одно большое свойство-массив (например, `$this->fm`, `$this` — наш класс) и в нем создаю лямба-функции. Таким образом, если я хочу, например, получить информацию о папке, я вызываю `$this->fm['folder']("/test")`. Этот вариант мне тоже кажется не суперкрасивым, скажите, пожалуйста, так вообще можно делать и есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: >>Подключать файловый менеджер извне не представляется возможным

Это еще почему? И как реализовано сейчас? Все, что требует менеджера напрямую наследуется от него что ли?

А что вы будете делать, если потребуется еще например подключить шифрование и окажется, что  "подключать извне не представляется возможным"? Изобретете множественное наследование?

В чем причина, не позволяющая подключить ФМ? Может стоит решить эту проблему и забыть о всех прочих проблемах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд вы где-то упустили из виду предстоящие проблемы с реализацией админки, но переписывать имеющиеся не выход. Красивее использовать конструкцию

```
$this->fm->folder("/test");
```

В перспективе или если есть возможность переписать код посмотрите в сторону [namespace](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: Я раньше использовал пространства имен, но потом они у меня по какой-то причине вышли из использования. Спасибо, я подумаю.

Answer (score 0):

почитайте про camelCase очень удобно - даже если названия похожи.

Comment: Ну я как раз описал, что camelCase мне не очень нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать больше одного слова.